# Connecting 4 tables using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently i am trying to write a query that will allow me pull data from four different tables . This is a brief idea of what my tables look like and how they are connecting: [image]

I can get the query to connect to the medicine and userdiagnosis tables from the usermedication table ok, but when i try to connect the diagnosis table from the userdiagnosis table the query will not run. I am trying to pull the diagnosis text from the diagnosis table.

This is the query i am running now but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
var api = {
// an example of executing a SQL statement directly
get: (request, response, next) => {
    var query = {
        sql: 'SELECT  dbo.usermedication.id, \
        dbo.medicine.id AS medicationid,  \
        dbo.medicine.medname, \
        dbo.usermedication.isactive, \
        dbo.usermedication.reminder, \
        dbo.usermedication.communityfeedback, \
        dbo.usermedication.frequency, \
        dbo.usermedication.directions, \
        dbo.medicine.dosage, \
        dbo.usermedication.datetimetotake,  \
        dbo.userdiagnosis.id as "userdiagnosisid", \
        dbo.diagnosis.id AS diagnosisid, \
        dbo.diagnosis.diagnosistext \
        FROM dbo.usermedication, dbo.userdiagnosis 
INNER JOIN dbo.medicine ON dbo.usermedication.medicationid = dbo.medicine.id  
INNER JOIN dbo.userdiagnosis ON dbo.usermedication.userdiagnosisid = dbo.userdiagnosis.id  
INNER JOIN dbo.diagnosis ON dbo.userdiagnosis.diagnosisid = dbo.diagnosis.id 
WHERE dbo.usermedication.userid = @userid AND dbo.usermedication.isactive = 1',
        parameters: [
            { name: 'userid', value: request.query.userid }
        ]
    };

    request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
        .then(function (results) {
            response.json(results);
        });
}
};

     module.exports = api;
```

I am currently running this off azure easy api's and using xamarin forms. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Doesnt seem to be working" is a pretty broad description. Is there any error message given? What happens instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase On my app i have an 'busy indicator' running when the data is loading and an error message when the data doesnt load, all it does now is loads for ages and then just stops, it doesnt seem to picking the data up from the api on azure

Comment: And have you checked for errors?

Comment: @NicoHaase i had the userdiagnosis table listed twice, that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbo.userdiagnosis` is listed twice (note the comma in the `FROM` line)... don't join tables with commas.